# Transparent object in QT3D

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt3d

I need to be able to change the transparency of a mesh object in QT3D. I am using a Scene3D component as the root which contains a default ForwardRenderer.

```
components: [
    RenderSettings {
        activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
            clearColor: Qt.rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)
            camera: camera


        }
    },
    // Event Source will be set by the Qt3DQuickWindow
    InputSettings { }
]
```

My 3D object is made up of a Mesh, Transform and PhongMaterial.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is ok. You can change your model to see the effect. The full code is:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.0
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
import Qt3D.Extras 2.0
import Qt3D.Input 2.0 

Teapot{
    x: 0; y:0; z:0;
    material: PhongAlphaMaterial{
        ambient: Qt.rgba( 1, 0, 0, 1.0 )
        diffuse: Qt.rgba( 1, 0, 0, 1.0 )
        specular: Qt.rgba(1, 0, 0, 1.0 )
        shininess: 1.0
        alpha: 0.5
    }
}
```

Teapot image

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The code was actually completely correct. I found out the issue. My build is based of QT5.7.0 and my 3D entities are rendered in a Scene3D. I found out that there is a known bug in QT 5.7.0 when using a PhongAlphaMaterial inside a Scene3D. I took the code base and build it in QT5.8 and it worked perfectly. So thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You are welcome ! Qt 3D is under developing, and often change it's apis to fix bugs. It's a good choice to install Qt 5.9.1 right now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use PhongAlphaMaterial:

```
PhongAlphaMaterial{
    id: redMaterial
    ambient: Qt.rgba( 1, 0, 0, 1.0 )
    diffuse: Qt.rgba( 1, 0, 0, 1.0 )
    specular: Qt.rgba(1, 0, 0, 1.0 )
    shininess: 1.0
    alpha: 0.4
}
```

Comment: Ok I will try that out and get back to you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just tried the PhongAlphaMaterial but it resulted in my object just appearing as black. It has a really small red outline of the object